# How do I get xx="$£A" to be a 3 character string

Tags: python, encoding, arrays

I am using Python 2.7

If I set a variable to xx = '$£A' I get a 4 byte string. This is because the £ character has a value > 127.
In my script, the first line is:

coding=latin_1

then further down I have tried:
xx = bytearray(B'$£A').decode('latin_1')
if I print str(len(xx)), I get the value 4.

All I need is as byte array to contain three bytes, ascii value for $, 163=ANSI Latin_1 for £ and ascii value for A.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Is your source code actually saved as Latin-1...?

Comment: Thanks for this, the script file itself was being saved as utf-8. Save it as an ansi, and all is ok

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous to use characters above 128 unescaped in string constants unless:

- you have a line `# coding=xxx` as first or second line in your script
- your editor uses the declared encoding

The recommended way is to escape them:

```
xx = b'$\xa3A'
```

(above would give the correct latin1 string in Python 2 or the correct latin1 encoded bytes in Python 3, whatever the local encoding could be)